# Is there a porting mode in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, porting

In short: I've got a library. It's not currently Windows Phone 8 compatible, and I'd like to make it so. What I'm wondering is does Visual Studio have an easy way of porting a current class library project from one version of .NET to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your project to a portable class library (PCL). Normally you'd start with a PCL from scratch, but there is a hacky way to convert an existing library. Which is described in this blog post:

http://geekswithblogs.net/imilovanovic/archive/2012/08/31/vs2012---how-to-manually-convert-.net-class-library-to.aspx

Once your library is a PCL, you can enable windows phone as a target, and you'll get exceptions on everything that is not comparable.

Comment: You mean visual studio express? I'm not sure, I don't have the installed. But if VS express supports PCLs, I dont see why not.